# Select values from a table given a range in a column and a foreign key assosciated with it

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Here is a table Lunchmenu

```
    [MenuID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [MenuDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [MenuItem] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] FOREIGN KEY NULL,
```

How to select all menu items within a date range for a given client id USING SQL and LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Sql it would be something like:

```
Select * from LunchMenu where MenuDate between '01/12/13' and '02/12/13' and ClientId = @clientid
```

linq would be something like where vClientId is the value passed in etc....:

```
var result = from r in context.LunchMenu
where r.Menudate >= "01/02/13" && r.MenuDate <= "02/12/13" && r.ClientID = vClientId
select r;
```